# Get react-select selected option when using multi dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have two working [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/) drop downs on my page, one that allows the user to select A or B, and one that allows them to choose multiple items from "blue, yellow , red".

When they have chosen these items, I want to use them. For now I just want to check the values that have been selected, so I'm just printing them to screen. For the single selection drop down I have used the example code from the github successfully. This is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'a', label: 'a' },
  { value: 'b', label: 'b' },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    document.write(`Option selected:`, selectedOption.value); //this prints the selected option
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
        //isMulti //added when the user can pick more than one
      />
    );
  }
}
```

My question is how do I successfully do this for the multi option? The user can select as many as they wish, but an 'undefined' error is thrown when it prints the option that has been selected. I think this is because the option is stored in an array but I'm not sure.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to change the `handleChange` to deal with the `isMulti`. Here's an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'a', label: 'a' },
  { value: 'b', label: 'b' },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOptions: [],
  }

  handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOptions });
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedOptions } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Select
          isMulti
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={options}
        />
      {selectedOptions.map(o => <p>{o.value}</p>)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-czf4ib

Comment: This is great and works perfectly, thank you. I was just wondering if you mind explaining this line  {this.state.selectedOptions.map(o => <p>{o.value}</p>)}. If I wanted to do something else with the values, like pass them somewhere, would I be able to do this here in place of the <p>...<p/> code?

Comment: Sure thing. That code is just mapping over the options from `state` to display them. You can access the options and do whatever you want with them by accessing `this.state.selectedOptions`. Ideally you wouldn't do it in `render()` however.

Comment: any idea how to get the value while setting state, I'd like to send an array of all select values to the backend

Comment: @Cozy not really sure what you mean. Can you ask a full question somewhere and I'll take a look.

Comment: Wanted to extract all selected values and push them to an array which I will later store in state and post to backend. I was able to achieve this as follows ```handleSelectedOptions = (selectedOptions) => {
  let values = [];
  selectedOptions.map((v) => values.push(v.value));

  this.setState((state) => ({
   ...state,
   tags: values
  }));
 };```

Comment: This is not a working example. selectedOption does not exist and therefore the values show up correctly. I'll be working on a fix (hopefully) to get it working.

Comment: values={selectedOptions}

Answer (score 12):

If you are using react hooks, here is how you can get the selected values from the `react-select` with `isMulti` prop.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { handleSubmit } = useForm();

const options = [
  { value: 'a', label: 'a' },
  { value: 'b', label: 'b' },
];

const FormComponent = (props) => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (options) => {
    setSelectedOptions(options);
  };

  const onSubmit = (formData, event) => {
     console.log("Form Data: ", formData)
     console.log("Selected Options: ", selectedOptions)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Select
          isMulti = {true}
          options={options}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          onChange={handleChange}/>

     <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: works like charm .. thanks :)

Comment: very concise and to the point.. worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

For store value in array try this one
 [ "purple", "red", "blue" ]

```
 handleChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    let catArray = [];
    selectedOptions.map(o => 
       catArray.push(o.value)
   );

   this.setState({selectedOptions:catArray});
}
```

onChange={this.handleChange}