# How to get data from a multi select from the "React-Select" library?

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit, multi-select, react-select

In my react app for something like:

```js
const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // What do I do here?
}

return (
<form onSubmit={submitForm}>
    <Select name='ex' options={optionsList} isMulti />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
);
```

If user selects "option 1" and "option 3" this is able to get something like a list of the selected options, something like ["option1", "option3"] or even like {"ex": ["option1", "option3"]}

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191753/get-react-select-selected-option-when-using-multi-dropdown

Comment: Does not answer my question, I want to get the data when the form is finally submitted, along with all of the other form elements like regular inputs.

Comment: You should store selected values out of React Select component in a state. Then read the values from that state on form submit. How to do this? The above linked post answers that.