# React-Select Multi - Modify Hooks Array Wth Each Selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror, react-select

I want to use `react-select` to append values to a hooks array. When I select from a selected option, I would like the item to be pushed into the hooks array, and when the user gets rid of the item, I would like the hooks array to update as well.

Here are my `teams`:

```
const teams = [
  { label: "Arsenal", value: 42 },
  { label: "Aston Villa", value: 66 },
  { label: "Brentford", value: 55 }
];
```

I want to put them all into a `comparedTeams` array hook, and update the hook `onChange`:

```
  const [comparedTeams, setComparedTeams] = useState([]);

    return (
          <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
            <Select
              isMulti
              name="select-teams"
              options={teams}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setComparedTeams([...comparedTeams, e.label]);
              }}
            />
          </div>
        );
```

However, whenever I add the item, I keep getting this error:

[image]

How do I get the hooks array to update when a user fires an `onChange`?

Comment: this might be as simple as you're not passing an array to `setComparedTeams`. Try `setComparedTeams([...comparedTeams, e.label])` instead

Comment: @asyncawait Ah thanks. Yes, classic mistake... But now I've done that, every update to the array comes back as `undefined`. Removing a team also adds an `undefined` to the array...

Comment: maybe you are intending to use `e.target.label` instead of `e.label`?

Comment: @asyncawait That results in Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'label')...

Comment: Hard to tell why your array is defined from the current question. If you make a repo I'm happy to take a look, but I think for the purposes of this question, passing an array is the issue at hand  You should want to check every spot the value changes and potentially log the values you are passing in and the value afterwards each time. You can create a `changeValue` function which uses `setComparedTeams` to handle the logging and debugging of why the value is undefined.

Comment: I managed to find a suitable answer here in the end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191753/get-react-select-selected-option-when-using-multi-dropdown